# Char assignment to *char not working

Tags: c, pointers, char, variable-assignment

Here is a function used in my main. The issue lies in `char` assignment.

```
void takeTurn(int *iap, int *tile, char *cap) {
    //*iap is 1 right now

    printf("\nThe current active player is %d. His character is %c", *iap, *cap);
    //prints The current active player is 1. His character is q.

    if (*iap == 1) *cap == 'X';
    if (*iap == 2) *cap == 'O';

    printf("\nThe current active player is %d. His character is %c", *iap, *cap);.
    //prints The current active player is 1. His character is q.

    . . . 
}
```

What needs to be done so the `*cap` assigns the proper `char` to the proper active player?

Comment: `*cap == 'X'` --> `*cap = 'X'`

Comment: Yes, this was a very silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `==` equality comparison operator where you should be using the `=` assignment operator instead.

Change these statements:

```
*cap == 'X';
*cap == 'O';
```

To these instead:

```
*cap = 'X';
*cap = 'O';
```

Comment: I feel silly not to have noticed that. Thank you.